# How to record mic from client then send to server

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, fetch, recording, mediastream

I would like to record microphone input from the client and then when he stops, send the data to the server and then output the recorded audio to a specific folder.

So far I have for the recording on the client I have followed [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API)

```
mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
   console.log("recorder stopped");

   const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });

   chunks = [];

   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('audio-file', blob);

   return fetch('http://localhost:3000/notes', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
   });

}
```

console.log(blob) on the client returns an object

```
Blob { size: 35412, type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" }
```

On the server side I use Node.js

```
app.post("/notes",function(req,res){
  console.log(req);
});
```

The server receives formData but the body is empty {}

I have also tried XMLHttpRequest with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played about with this type of project before. I created a simple form that allows you to record from the microphone, then upload to the server.

Sound files will be saved in ./sound_files

Just run the node server like

node server.js

And go to localhost:3000 to view the page.

**Node code (server.js)**

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
    
const storage = multer.diskStorage(
    {
        destination: './sound_files/',
        filename: function (req, file, cb ) {
            cb( null, file.originalname);
        }
    }
);

const upload = multer( { storage: storage } );

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static('./'));

app.post("/notes", upload.single("audio_data"), function(req,res){
    res.status(200).send("ok");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Express server listening on port: ${port}...`);
});
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Speech to text test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="padding:50px;">
    <h1>Speech to text test</h1>
    <div id="controls">
    <button id="recordButton">Record</button>
    <button id="transcribeButton" disabled>Stop and upload to server</button>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/08e7abd9/dist/recorder.js"></script>
    <script>
                
        let rec = null;
        let audioStream = null;

        const recordButton = document.getElementById("recordButton");
        const transcribeButton = document.getElementById("transcribeButton");

        recordButton.addEventListener("click", startRecording);
        transcribeButton.addEventListener("click", transcribeText);

        function startRecording() {

            let constraints = { audio: true, video:false }

            recordButton.disabled = true;
            transcribeButton.disabled = false;

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
                const audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
                audioStream = stream;
                const input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                rec = new Recorder(input, { numChannels: 1 })
                rec.record()
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Recording started..."
            }).catch(function(err) {
                recordButton.disabled = false;
                transcribeButton.disabled = true;
            });
        }

        function transcribeText() {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Converting audio to text..."
            transcribeButton.disabled = true;
            recordButton.disabled = false;
            rec.stop();
            audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
            rec.exportWAV(uploadSoundData);
        }

        function uploadSoundData(blob) {
            const filename = "sound-file-" + new Date().getTime() + ".wav";
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("audio_data", blob, filename);
            
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/notes', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }).then(async result => { 
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = await result.text();
            }).catch(error => { 
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "An error occurred: " + error;
            })
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, I have understood the node js part, but I am trying to use react js on client side, instead of `index.html` I want to use `Recorder.js` file. Is there any way I can change this `index.html` code to use it in a react js file? I tried to, but couldn't.

Comment: I haven't tried a react.js frontend with this, I'm sure it's doable, but I don't have a lot of experience with React unfortunately.